# Avoid using the "tex" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

There is an increasing number of questions on the parent site which are being tagged with [*tex*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex) and [*latex*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex). Although the second one could be justified in some cases, the first one doesn't have any sense in a site specifically devoted to TeX questions (it is like tagging a question *programming* in [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) or *maths* in [mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.net)). **I think the *tex* tag is redundant and should be removed.**

Answer (score 13):

If one could guarantee that the 'tex' tag was used to mean 'this is a question about the bowels of TeX, if you don't know the difference between `\def` and `\edef` then don't read any further' then I would argue that there was a place for it.  However, the parallel universe where that happens is nowhere near this one so I second the proposal.

Comment: Agreed, but I think your ideal meaning of `[tex]` would be useful, so it might be nice if it could be called something else. Like `[tex-core]` or `[tex-internals]`.

Comment: You could use initex for these.

Comment: I think initex could mean something completely different in the TeX world.

Comment: Remember that tags get auto-suggested.  I would have the tag _start_ with 'tex' so that it gets picked up when someone types 'tex' into the tag field.  I prefer 'tex-core' over 'tex-internals'; to me, the latter suggests the tex source code itself.

Comment: @juannavar: Initex is the pure primitive language that is generally used for defining format files, such as Plain Tex and Latex.

Answer (score 8):

I actually think the `latex` tag is the useless one. Most users coming to this site are probably dealing with LaTeX and, by default, our answers should be as most LaTeX-friendly as possible, using robust macros and packages. And *only* if the question is tagged as `tex` (or maybe `tex-core` or maybe `macros` or maybe something else?) we know that the poster has some TeX experience and is confident with using low-level commands.

Comment: I don't think that that is a safe assumption, though.  I think that lots of questions will get tagged "tex" which aren't really about _deep down_ TeX.

Comment: Then those questions shouldn't be tagged `tex`. Maybe, as others suggested, `plain-tex`?

Comment: So Context and Plain Tex questions are implicitly Latex question?  In fact, if you are searching, the ability to look for non-latex question using -[latex] is useful.

Answer (score 6):

I have never used plain TeX, only LaTeX. Maybe the tag should be **plain-tex**? For those who are not using any metapackages, or what to do something cool using plain TeX.

Comment: Plain TeX _is_ a meta package!  Wikipedia says: "Knuth's original default format, _which adds_ about 600 commands, is Plain TeX" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Huh =) didn't know that. Oh god tagging these two correctly will be a pain.

Comment: @Andrew: Plain Tex is a macro package on top of initex.

Comment: So why not keep tex, initex and latex tags. But don't use them if the question is just about "normal" latex. If the question is specifically about the initex core, i would add "initex". Or if it specifically asks about a non-latex, plain-tex solution, i would add "tex". Etc...

Comment: @Johannes: because if the tag exists, it will be misused. Better not allow the tag at all (and new users cannot create new tags).

Answer (score 4):

Is either of them useless?

What if I want to ask how to do X in LaTeX? I'm not interested in answers talking about how to do it in regular TeX, or LyX or any other variants, just LaTeX. How should I tag it?

Likewise, what if I'm interested in how to do the same thing in TeX specifically? A LaTeX answer is no good to me.

Aren't both the tags justified then?

The problem obviously becomes enforcing this discipline (so `[tex]` doesn't end up on *every* question)

Or perhaps we should use [latex-only] and [tex-only] to indicate questions about those specifically?

Comment: That starst to sound like a more promising solution.

Comment: Yes, tags like `[latex-only]` and `[tex-only]` would be better IMHO.

Comment: [latex-only] and [tex-only] seem also good solutions to me.

Comment: Note that by _leading_ with the key word, they'll be sure to come up in the tagging suggestions.

Comment: Somehow i don't really like "[latex-only]". Such a tag would indicate a preferred form of answers, and not describe the content of the question. If a question "only contains latex", then why would the tag be not called "[latex]"

Answer (score 1):

I think it is true that most questions will be LaTeX related. (I've tagged some things with the latex tag, but not without some concern.)

However, the tex tag *is* needed, I think. I answered [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-to-get-long-ttext-sections-to-break) in LaTeX terms, then saw the tex tag, and deleted my answer. I've also commented on two other answers along the lines of "LaTeX answer to TeX question". I wasn't sure that it was a TeX not LaTeX question until I saw the tex tag.

Comment: I think it's fine to give a "LaTeX" answer to a "TeX" question. Maybe unless the question has a `really-tex-only` or `plain-tex` tag, the OP might have added the `tex` tag to say "hey I'm fine with tex-hacks", but he will be happy to know that there is a simpler/more robust LaTeX solution to his problem.

Comment: But, if I am using TeX, how is a "here's what to do in LaTeX" answer much better than a "you do this in MS Word" one?

Comment: *"unless the question has a `really-tex-only` or `plain-tex` tag"*

Comment: you could see how the LaTeX package does things?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the existing answers I propose to have the following tags:

- `tex-hacks` for meaning "I know about `\def` and `\edef` so TeX hack-ish answers are fine
  for me. But hey, I'll also welcome any LaTeX answers too!"
- `plain-tex`, `latex`, `context`, etc. for meaning "I only care about answers for this
  particular set of macro extensions. Don't bother me with anything outside of this scope!"

A lone `tex` tag should then be ditched and replaced with a more specific one, i.e. either `tex-hacks` or `plain-tex`.

Comment: Too much complicated, or not very intuitive at least. Tags like [tex-only], [latex-only] and so on should be enough to cover all that cases.

Comment: From the comments above there is a need to distinguish between what you call `tex-only` and what I call `tex-hacks`, does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Btw, this answer is a community-wiki so feel free to edit and improve the proposal rather than just down-vote it.

Comment: A `hacks` tag should be enough if you're asking something 'hack-ish' (as you put it), along with a `tex-only` if you want to specify that you're asking about a tex hack. How does it sound? `tex-hacks` is redundant having those two tags, but that is just my opinion, I can be wrong.