# Our set of tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

After a few questions about tags, meta-tags, what is valid and what should not, I thought it would be useful to keep all of this information in one place. Eventually this will be also useful to populate our FAQ.

It's a CW so everybody is free to edit. Let's keep the general guidelines in the question, and discuss about issues with specific tags on individual answers.

### Recommended Tags

The following kinds of tags are recommended:

- Formats, compilers, and tools e.g.: [luatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luatex), [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex), [bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibtex), [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context), ... (but *not* [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex), see below)
- Package and class names, e.g.: [tikz-pgf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf), [hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hyperref), [amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amsmath), ...
- Command and environment names, e.g.: [itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/itemize), [hbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hbox), ...
- Specific topics, e.g.: [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros), [fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fonts), [graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), [errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/errors), [floats](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats), ... *(Note: prefer plural nouns)*
- Specific actions, e.g.: [installing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installing), [compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/compiling), [debugging](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging), [citing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citing), ... *(Note: prefer -ing verb form)*

The following math related tags are recommended:

- Use [math-mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math-mode) for questions about typesetting the content of math formulas.
- Use [equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equations) for questions about how to include equations in a document
  (e.g. the `equation`, `gather`, `align`, etc. environments)
- Use [symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/symbols) for queries about how to produce specific symbols. But only if
  the [comprehensive list](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/comprehensive.html) or the [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) online tool can't answer your
  question.

Questions such as *What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?*, where many good answers are expected and none will be the right answer, should take the [big-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) tag, and should normally be marked *Community Wiki*.

### Discouraged tags

- Meta-tags, i.e. tags about the kind of question or the person asking the question,
  but not about the *content* or *topic* of the question.

  Examples: [subjective](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective), [beginners](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginners), [best-practices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices).

  A special exception is made for the [big-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) tag, which is a meta-tag.
- The [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) or [latex2e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex2e) tags. Questions are, by default, assumed to be about
  the LaTeX language/system. Unless your question is *specifically* about another
  format (e.g. [context](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/context)) or *specifically* about a TeX compiler (e.g. [pdftex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdftex)),
  **you don't need to specify you're using LaTeX**.
- The [tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex) tag. If your question is specifically about TeX primitives or the TeX
  system (as opposed to LaTeX), **use [tex-core](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tex-core) instead**. If your question is about
  using low-level TeX commands to define a macro then use the [macros](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros) tag.

Comment: We should be careful not to flood the front page with old questions where we updated the tags.

Comment: @Caramdir: damn, true. Fortunately, this won’t be a problem once the tag synonyms are [automatically applied by the system](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: @Caramdir, I was also thinking about this. Is there any better way to retag questions, maybe as moderators? Or should we request a feature that retagging doesn't promote questions to the frontpage?

Comment: Edited to contain exception for [big-list] meta-tag, per http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336/faq-request-encourage-use-of-big-list-meta-tag

Comment: Just a note that we should all keep an eye on the synonyms page so that sensible ones get voted for!

Comment: What if there's a name clash between different categories of tags? `graphics` first comes to mind, as it could be either about the package, or about graphics as a topic. I suppose this would pop up with other generically-named packages. How these would be distinguished then?

Comment: @mindcorrosive: For this particular case I think the single tag `graphics` can be used for both meanings. As questions about one meaning will helpfully be also relevant to the other.

Comment: @Martin: If necessary, tags like `[graphics-package]` could be used.

Answer (score 8):

**What should we do about the `[latex]` tag?**

There was an [earlier discussion](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51/avoid-using-the-tex-tag), but I really think there was no consensus. Moreover, now that the site has been running for a few days we can see how these tags have been used so far.

As of now, the `[latex]` tag is completely useless. The large majority of questions in the site are about LaTeX anyway, but only a few of them are tagged so. Even worst some questions are *only* tagged `[latex]` which is, in my view, completely useless. So I would also suggest in this case to **discourage** using the `[latex]` tag, since it is the "default" topic, unless another (`[plain-tex]`, `[luatex]`, `[context]`, etc.) is specified.

Thoughts?

Comment: Since you mentioned `[luatex]`: Is there a tag for the "default" (i.e., non-pdf) TeX compiler?

Comment: I think you’re right about the [latex] tag, even though it could be useful in questions such as “TeX versus LaTeX”. But I think restricting it to that usage will be a fight against windmills. As for [plain-tex], see my own answer.

Comment: @Caramdir, I think it should be `plain-tex`, but I'm still not sure. See Konrad's answer.

Comment: I've edited my question to contain only the discussion about `[latex]`, and left Konrand's answer for `[tex]`. Another question here, would there be a way to completely ban this tag and prevent users from using it in the future?

Comment: Hmm.. I just found that at some point I suggested to add `[latex2e]` as a synonym of `[latex]`. I now think *both* should be discouraged, for precisely the same reasons.

Comment: @Caramdir: *Is there a tag for the "default" (i.e., non-pdf) TeX compiler?* - I think [web2c] would work for it (Web2C might be used to mean: a technology for converting Knuth's Web programs to compilable C, the results of applying it to Tex, or the whole of the kpathsea-centric system of programs around it).  But it's maybe too cryptic for beginners.

Comment: So I still don't get this, but I thought "tex-core" was meant as a tag for the TeX language (with or without "plain"), as well as the "default" tex compiler. In any case, I think that there will be very few questions about "any" of these "sub" cases of what "TeX" (or "tex") means. And for the few people that can tell the difference, a single tag for all of those uses should be more than enough.

Comment: @Charles @Juan: When I typed that question about the default compiler, I was under the impression that `pdflatex` and `latex` invoke two different programs. This is not the case (the both invoke pdfTeX/eTeX), so the question is obsolete.

Comment: Shouldn't we use `latex2e` for things directly relating to the current kernel? For example, processing package and class options, internal functions such as `\@for`, _etc_.?

Comment: What I fear is that it would be very hard to make people consistently use this tag, they will just apply it to everything. How about `latex-core`?

Comment: Okay, is there an agreement to systematically sort this one out? There are currently ~70 `latex` tags, and it might be good to deal with them before there are hundreds!

Comment: We have the hope that, when we get moderators, they should be able to deal with this. Is there a tag kill-switch? Should we ask for such a feature?

Comment: `latex-core` is a good idea. What should we do with questions like ["Why should I use LaTeX?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/why-should-i-use-latex)? Without the `latex` tag I can't think of a tag that applies.

Answer (score 6):

**Discourage the use of the `[tex]` tag, use `[tex-core]` instead.**

My suggestion:

since “Plain TeX” seems to denote something else than TeX, let’s have the following tag alias:

**`tex`** => **`tex-core`**

This should be easy enough to find. I would very much like to set up the synonym while the `tex` tag is still only scarcely used. Once it’s used more often, setting up the synonym will be impossible, since the `tex` tag will appear more often than `tex-core` (and the Stack Exchange app then prevents setting up the synonym).

I’ve introduced the synonym. **Please [vote for it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=tex-core&sort=info&pagesize=15) so that questions will be retagged automatically!**

Comment: I still haven't figured this out completely, could you please explain the difference between `tex-core` and `plain-tex`?

Comment: Should we have `[plain-tex]` for the "plain" TeX compiler (i.e. the program invoked with `tex` or `latex`) and `[tex-core]` for the language TeX? (NB: in TeX Live `tex` and `latex` actually invoke different programs?)

Comment: I would rather have just one tag for the two meanings (there won't be many questions about this anyway, and people interested in one is also probably interested the other). I'm happy with having `tex-core` for both.

Comment: @Juan: According to [Andrew’s and Charles’ comments](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51/avoid-using-the-tex-tag/64#64), “Plain TeX” is a macro collection on top of TeX (more precisely, `initex`). But I’m not necessarily against it. It just seemed on the other thread that [tex-core] had a lot of supporters. Anyway, now that the [tex] tag is eradicated, a moderator (as soon as we get one) can change the actual [tex-*] tag to whatever gets the most votes.

Comment: Just one question: is this overcomplicating matters? If a newcomer wants to search for an answer to his TeX question, will he know/be able to guess which tags to search? We don't have to define some kind of precise and all-encompassing taxonomy with zero ambiguity. We just need to do what we can to ensure that the tags that are used provide added value. If someone is just starting out with TeX, and wants to ask some simple question, they are going to assume that `tex-core` is different, probably about the "guts" of the system.

Comment: @jalf: tag synonyms also work in search (I’ve just tried it, I’m surprised myself)! So if a new user searches for `[tex]` they get the search results for `[tex-core]`. As for asking questions, new users cannot create new tags – that means if a user tries to use `[tex]` in their question, this will either be disallowed or retagged (I’m not sure which and I don’t want to try now).

Answer (score 5):

**"Concept" vs "command" tags?**

According to your list for packages/commands that are named after concepts, we should have two tags: The command name (usually singular) and the concept name (in plural form). E.g. we have the `[matrix]` tag (for the environment), but questions about matrices (with various commands) should be tagged `[matrices]`. What should we do about those tags?

Comment: This is a good question. I think that, generally, the "concept" should win over the "command", specially if there are many different "commands" that could be related to the "concept". Therefore, I would prefer "matrices" since there are many commands (array, matrix, pmatrix, ..) related to the same concept.

Comment: @Juan: I see that you have retagged questions accordingly. Perhaps you also want to vote for the [synonym proposal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=matrices&sort=info&pagesize=15) to get the retagging automated.

Comment: done! just voted for your proposal

Answer (score 3):

**`[compiling]`, `[compile]` or `[compilation`] (and similar tags)**

By the suggestion in the original post here, we should have `[installing]`, `[compiling]`, `[debugging]`, etc. There are currently the following suggestion of tags synonyms open:

- [compiling] -> [compilation]
- [installation] -> [install]
- [print] -> [printing]

I don't really mind which form we take, but we should at least try to be consistent.

Comment: I've created the synonym [print] -> [printing] and thought the same. While adding some synonyms (toc, subscript, superscript, table, symbol) I came to compilation to but chose this as the master just because it's been more used. But it may be downvoted and vanish. I agree completely that the tags should sound similar and should be consistent. This makes it easier for a questioner to choose tags or to create reasonable new one.

Comment: I agree, we should have [compiling], [installing], [printing], etc., as suggested in the original post.

Comment: Now that we have moderators: Could someone please rename the tags.

Comment: Done for the mentioned tags.

Comment: Thank you! (and some additional characters)

Answer (score 2):

**What about math related tags?**

Another question: What is the tag for math mode. E.g. if someone asks about a symbol for use in an equation, there are currently several possible tags to choose from: `[math]`, `[mathmode]`, `[equations]` and of course no tag i.e. only `[symbol]` (which btw should be plural?).

Comment: My suggestion is keep `[mathmode]` about the content of math formula (and make `[math]` a synonym). While `[equations]` is about how to layout equations on a document (e.g. the equation/align/gather wrapper). Then `[symbols]` should be about individual glyphs (`[glyph]` should be a synonym), and this questions should anyway be discouraged, pointing users to, e.g. the comprehensive list or [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Comment: @Juan: on the other hand, there are currently more `[math]` questions than `[mathmode]`. At the very least, this means that we cannot create a synonym straight away. Agree about `[symbols]`.

Comment: I know, but I prefer `[mathmode]` because it's more specific. If people here in meta like this idea, and when we get moderators, we can do the switch.

Comment: The tags are merged into `[mathmode]`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest "compilation" as a synonym of "compiling", but this doesn't seem to be possible, as "compilation" is more common than "compiling". Now what?

Another example: "template" as a synonym of "templates".

Comment: We have to wait to get moderators in order to do those. Also we probably should set synonyms only for the most common miss-taggings. Trying to "synonymize" every possible variation of tags would be too tedious and impractical. Probably as a rule of thumb, don't suggest a synonym that has only be used once or twice (it would be far easier simply to retag those)

Comment: I thought synonyms would be better than retagging as it won't promote the questions to the front page?

Comment: I understand your thought, but there should be a better solution. Maybe just wait until we have moderators who can hopefully do more powerful tag managing.

Comment: Both tags are done.

Comment: as I understand it, synonyms aren't retroactive, so you still end up having to retag somehow. Why is it such a big deal for stuff to end up on the front page?

Answer (score 2):

**Should hyphenation be encouraged or discouraged?**

In the suggested tag synonyms there is `[math-mode]` -> `[mathmode]` but `[tableofcontents]` -> `[table-of-contents]`. This feels rather inconsistent, especially considering that the command is named `\tableofcontents`.

Comment: Well, we already have list-of-figures and list-of-tables, so I thought table-of-contents would make more sense.

Comment: I tend to like the names with hyphens. But for some reason `mathmode` is funny, a google search for "mathmode" (with quotes) is about 26K hits, while "math mode" yields 34K hits but this *includes* the ones for "mathmode" (without the space), so really there are only 8K uses of "math mode". In the (La)TeX world maybe people really use the term "mathmode"?

Answer (score 2):

## AMS tags

I'm not sure about the 'ams -> amsmath' suggestion.  The AMS has more packages than just 'amsmath', in particular they have their 'amsref' stuff.  I would regard the 'ams' tag as ambiguous, and so not as one that is synonymous with another tag.  Rather, whenever 'ams' rears its ugly head, it should be retagged to an *appropriate* tag.

To expand on that, synonymous tags should really be synonymous.  I think that the most obvious examples being singular to plural, or no-hyphens to hyphens.  Where a tag is ambiguous or just plain useless, the questions should be retagged and the tag effectively dropped.

Comment: (Note that the `ams` tag does not exist anymore.)

Comment: Note some such tags might need to be banned, if they are recreated again and again...

Answer (score 2):

Now that we have moderators, could someone also rename `[error]` -> `[errors]` and leave `[error]` as a synonym?

Comment: ok, it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have invented the [best-practices] tag for [Best practices references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577/best-practices-references).  Note than in this particular case, [best-practices] was *not* a meta-tag, since best practices were precisely the topic of the question.

Comment: I have to say I don't like neither the question nor the tag, but well, what the heck.

Answer (score 1):

**Tagging `header-footer` *versus* separate `header` and `footer` tags?**

I see that several questions are tagged `header-footer`. To me, these feel like two separate tags, although I can also see that they often go together. Is the general feeling that we should always pick `header-footer` (*i.e.* discourage `header` and `footer` separately)?

Comment: I think just having the one tag `header-footer` should be enough.

Comment: @Juan: That's probably best, considering that most techniques and packages applicable to the one are also applicable to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Could someone with enough rights please remove the `beginners` tag from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that-closed

Comment: The question was closed, but I've done it anyway.

Comment: I know, because otherwise I would have removed the tag myself. This was just to remove the tag from the system, so that no one is tempted to use it.