# Questions migrated from stackoverflow.com: Remove the {latex} tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

This is an appeal to users with the privilege to retag questions, i.e., everyone with a reputation of 500 or more.

Questions that reach our site via migration from stackoverflow.com will almost invariably feature the [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag. Some of those questions will receive answers, while others will be closed as duplicates. However, the [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag should be removed *without exception*, because even a closed question featuring this tag allows users to apply [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) to new questions which is [Not A Good Thing](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/our-set-of-tags).

Bottom line: If you spot the [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag, *remove it* (and add appropriate tags instead).

Comment: Oops, I thought we do already have this automatic removal? But [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12953/1235) shows it doesn't work (reliably).

Comment: Relevant discussion here: [Problematic migration change](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/926/problematic-migration-change).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added an intrinsic tag of

`^(la)?tex$`

Intrinsic tags are considered "ambient" tags that exist on every question by dint of the site topic. These tags are auto-removed on migration to a target site, but also used as a test of suitability prior to the migration, e.g. if the question on the source site does not contain at least one tag in common with the destination site *including intrinsic tags* then the migration is disallowed.

Comment: Does that make these tags unavailable on the site? If so, [it did not work](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/13096/revisions).

Comment: @caramdir no, it does not

Answer (score 4):

As Hendrik says, any tag that does not exist here should be removed automatically. However, it seems like Igor recreated [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/12939/revisions) shortly before [the question Hendrik mentions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12953/1235) was merged and the tag wasn't yet completely removed from the database (indeed it is still available now; does anyone know how long it usually takes until a tag becomes unavailable?).

Maybe we should ask for the [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) to be completely blocked (this is possible, as far as I know).

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on this.