# package tag marginnote vs. command tag marginpar vs. feature of setting margin-notes

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [marginnote tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marginnote) is mentioned for questions about the package `marginnote`:

> {marginnote} is about typesetting non-floating notes in margins using the marginnote package.

However, AFAIK there is no tag for the feature of setting margin-notes. So often users use the tag {marginnote} also as a feature tag, even if they do not use package `marginnote`. There is also a [tag marginpar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marginpar) but it is describes as

> {marginpar} is a command that adds content to the margin of documents.

So this is a command tag related to `\marginpar`.

Feature tags AFAIK should use the plural. So could and should the confusion about tag {marginnote} be solved by adding a tag {margin-notes} or {marginnotes}? The description could be something like:

> {marginnotes} is about how to place notes like text, pictures or other objects into the left or right margin. It can be used in addition to tags like {marginpar} (`\marginpar` is a command that adds content to the margin of documents) or {marginnote} (`marginnote` is a package to set non-floating notes in margins) or {sidenotes} (`sidenotes` is a package that allows text, figures etc. in the margin) or other without such tags.

In this case all false usages of {marginnote} can simply be changed into the new tag (which also could be added to questions already using {marginnote}).

In the past I have already removed the {marginnote} tag of several question but I do not know, how to do so for questions about the feature of setting margin-notes without using package `marginnote`, e.g,

- [Remarks in changes package with RevTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/457398/9057)
- [How to get a column with keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/453659/9057)
- [How can I get a prespecified clearance from `parmargin` to the page edge?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447743/9057)
- [How can I combine overlapping marginnotes in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/418820/9057)
- [Margin notes with the same behaviour as footnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321874/9057)
- [What is the proper way to use marginfix in memoir?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/403192/9057)
- [How can I accomplish similar side notes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401820/9057)
- [package with memoir-like sidebar functionality for standard book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393456/9057)
- [asymmetric margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391383/9057)
- [Allocate margin for sidenotes only if there is one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386010/9057)

Answer (score 7):

There are only around 500 questions altogether, 60 of which have both tags. If someone is asking about putting text in the margins an answer may quite possibly use `marginnote` even if the questioner had not known of that package. So I don't think it is really possible to separate these things as tags on *questions*.

So I  would suggest that we merge the tags making marginpar and marginnote synonyms for marginnotes and changing the description of marginnotes to say that it covers all marginal notes whether made with marginnote package or standard `\marginpar` or other means.

Comment: In this case shouldn't the tag be named `marginnotes`, because https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/302/9057 says, topic notes should use the plural? And then shouldn't `sidenotes` also be a synonym?

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes and yes

Comment: If I understand you, you want a new tag `marginnotes` with a description more like "{marginnotes} is about how to place notes like text, pictures or other objects into the left or right margin, e.g., using command `\marginpar` or a package like `marginnote` or `sidenotes` or another approach". And the tags `marginnote`, `marginpar` and `sidenotes` should become a synonym to `marginnotes`. Correct? IMHO this would be fine too.

Comment: @Schweinebacke yes that's what I meant.